# Unit tests for Android Wear app

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, wear-os

Is it possible to create `JUnit` tests for `wear module` of my app?

I was looking around but find no information about this.

For mobile module I have created `androidTest` and test packages to create unit test. But nothing for `wear module`.

Comment: It's the same as writing unit test for normal Android code. Just create a folder under src/main/test and Android Studio will see it as your test folder.

Comment: My bad, so easy, thanks man!